# print the name of argument from the function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, format

How to can I print the name of argument from the function in Python:

```
def general_info(dataset):
    print('Info on dataset {}:').format( ??? )


general_info(df_visits)
```

The output I expect:

```
'Info on dataset df_visits:'
```

Comment: And what if the value being passed is referenced by more than one identifier, or none (e.g. `general_info("hi")` or `general_info(some_seq[index])`? The name isn't an attribute of the value.

Comment: Thank you very much  @jonrsharpe for pointing out the relevant answer to my question. **kwargs indeed helps me to get an argument name printed. Unfortunately, I still do not know how to place it inside of my string to make it part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the local name of the parameter this way:

```
def general_info(dataset):
    print(f"Info on {dataset=}")
```

But you cannot retrieve the name that was used in the call. It might not even have a name, or it might have more than one.

For example, what name would you expect to see printed in response to this?:

```
general_info("FRED")
```

Or for this, would you expect to see `a` or `b`?:

```
a = "FRED"
b = a
general_info(a)
```

The name is not an attribute of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using `**kwargs` maybe helps you here, since you can treat it as any dictionary and what you actually want is to print the keys.

```
def general_info(**kwargs):
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        print(k)
        print(f'Info on dataset {k}:')


general_info(df_visits=[], some_list=[1], some_str="qwerty")
```